# Is it worthwhile to replace FileInfo.Name() with Path.GetFileName()?

Tags: c#, fileinfo

Making some modification to an application that I inherited, and in a lot of places the original code uses this to get the name of a file without the path:

```
string filename = "C:\path\to\abc.xyz";
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filename);
string newfilename = Path.Combine(otherpath, fi.Name);
```

There is no need to check if the file exists or access any other properties of the actual file, there is just a need to extract the name portion of the full path.

This is not a real-time app, but its performance is kind of important. I am still learning .NET framework and C# and am under impression that creating `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` objects has some overhead which at run-time depends on the IO load of the OS.

My first move was to turn that into:

```
string newfilename = Path.Combine(otherpath, Path.GetFileName(filename));
```

There are dozens of lines where the same original code is used. Is my concern of this code being dependent on IO founded and am I correct in the assumption that my change would eliminate that dependency?

Comment: Wow, already some hate. What's wrong with you, people?

Comment: _Impressions_ could be easily confirmed or denied if you _measure_

Comment: ^translation: why don't you try it both ways and run some tests to see which one takes longer to run?

Comment: Are you proposing that I run an IO stress tool?

Comment: No, use both ways in normal application useage, and see if one is acceptable and one is not. If you can't notice a difference then it does not matter. Use the one that is easier for you to understand and maintain.

Comment: Yes, [don't let the perfect be the enemy of the good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_is_the_enemy_of_good)!

Comment: @ajeh...  IF   _There is no need to check if the file exists or access any other properties of the actual file, there is just a need to extract the name portion of the full path._  if you have the full path name... would not a simple filename.split('\') give you what you want. As the filename would be the last element from the returned split method?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it worthwhile to replace FileInfo.Name() with Path.GetFileName()?

You will have to judge that based on your application. We don't know how many times these calls happen in your critical paths and if the gain in performance is worth any benefit.

> Is my concern of this code being dependent on IO founded and am I correct in the assumption that my change would eliminate that dependency?

Using `Fileinfo` is better than using the equivalent `File` method when making more than one call which needs `stat`, since the `stat` info will be cached in the `FileInfo` object with the first call. In your case, you don't do any `stat` so there is no such "I/O" overhead. But when you use `FileInfo` it will do some security checks (registry access, dll loads, etc) - so you will have that overhead. `Path.GetFileName` is pretty much an abstraction for string manipulation, so it does not have any such overhead and will be faster.

If I were you, and had the luxury and time to make the change from `FileInfo` call to `Path.GetFileName`, I would do it. To me (and this is subjective), the `Path.GetFileName` call is lot "cleaner"